# Docker-compose - Cannot create container for service postgres

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on windows 10 trying to convert my flask app to docker flask app, the problem is it cannot create a container for postgres it shows this error:

`Successfully tagged news_web:latest
Creating news_postgres_1 ... error
ERROR: for news_postgres_1  Cannot create container for service postgres: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\DEV\news\pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: c:\users\user\desktop\dev\news\pgdata`

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:11.0
    expose:
    - "5432"
    volumes:
    - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

web:
    restart: always
    build: ./news
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
    volumes:
    - ./news:/usr/src/news/app
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    env_file:
    - ./news/.env
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    environment:
    - ENV=staging
    - POSTGRES_DB=newsdb
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123123
    - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this error says is that you do not have the proper directory that you're using as the source for the volume: `pgdata` which should be located in your `C:\Users\User\Desktop\DEV\news` folder.

Comment: What if i removed the volume, is it going to work? i mean is that will break the app?

Comment: It won't, but the data stored in the database will be lost after your container is removed.

Comment: What is the best way to save the data from being removed? is it good to create a docker app on windows or not the best choice ?

Comment: The best way is to use a volume, like you have it in the docker-compose file you posted. It's not the best choice, but it should be Ok for getting to know docker, if you don't have any better option (i.e. a Linux box ;))

Comment: So the solution is to create pgdata inside my app folder and map it to volume :)

Comment: Yeah, it's already mapped in this line: ' volumes: - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/'. You just need to create the folder.